# Insert Sort array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, complexity-theory

I have an array of nearly sorted ~1000 objects like `{val: N}` and sorting them by built-in `Array.prototype.sort`:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.val - b.val });
```

I've stumble upon http://jsperf.com/javascript-sort/16 and tried to use Insert Sort:

```
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var tmp = arr[i],
    j = i;
    while (arr[j-1].val > tmp.val) {
        arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        --j;
    }
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

but it always throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'kills' of undefined`.

Where to dig?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: lol! the performance numbers in http://jsperf.com/javascript-sort/16 are for a sorted array, for which this algorithm (unsurprisingly) takes linear time, instead of its well-known O(N^2) performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a bounds check on j in the loop:

```
while (j > 0 && arr[j-1].val > tmp.val) {
    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
    --j;
}
```